# Paragraph with text alignment and width of contained text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, standalone

I need a (centered) paragraph that has the width of the text that it contains. This text has to be centered/left-aligned/right-aligned (one of these).

The text contains newlines.

It is no problem to set this with a given width but as the text within the paragraph is variable I don't find a way to do this.

I am using the standalone documentclass.

[image]

This is the example with fixed height:

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 100px 0pt 100px}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor,lipsum,pbox,graphicx,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
{\fontsize{6}{9}\selectfont%hier schon setzenfür em/ex
\begin{minipage}{115em}


{\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\parbox[t][][t]{92em}{
\centering{}\textbf{EINE ÜBERSCHRIFT}
}\\[0ex]
\parbox[t][][t]{92em}{
\centering{}{\fontsize{5}{9}\selectfont{}Eine Unter-Überschrift}
}
\end{tabular}\\[3ex]
}
{\centering
\parbox[t][][t]{30em}{\raggedright{}Karl Meier\\[3ex]Gustav Henrich\\[3ex]Lisa Schöne\\[3ex]Anton Dachs\\[3ex]Fritz Blumenthal}\\
}

\end{minipage}
}%End fontsize
\end{document}
```

So right now, this parbox has a fixed width and the content is not centered properly:

[image]

I want it this way:

[image]

Here, the parbox has a width that is fitted to the content and thus it is centered correctly. I cannot use a fixed width as the content is generated by a script and therefore variable.

Comment: The your paragraph will have only one line, right? Btw why are you using `standalone`?

Comment: @JouleV No, it contains several lines (see added picture). Standalone is used to get a pdf without pages.

Comment: As far as I can understand English, a paragraph doesn't contain new lines or line breaks.

Comment: @JouleV Added code.

Comment: Added some illustrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't still not figure out why `standalone` is really needed in this case - adjusting contents in this class is not easy, when you can always change page size in normal classes.

As for the `\parbox`, I propose an alternative using Ti*k*Z nodes:

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 100px 0pt 100px}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor,lipsum,pbox,graphicx,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{6}{9}\selectfont
\begin{minipage}{115em}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \textbf{EINE ÜBERSCHRIFT}\\[0ex]
        {\fontsize{5}{9}\selectfont{}Eine Unter-Überschrift}
    \end{tabular}\\[3ex]
    \tikz\node[draw,align=left] {%
    Karl Meier\\[3ex]Gustav Henrich\\[3ex]Lisa Schöne\\[3ex]Anton Dachs lang lang lang lang\\[3ex]Fritz Blumenthal};
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing the `draw` option will remove the box.

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 100px 0pt 100px}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,pagecolor,lipsum,pbox,graphicx,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{6}{9}\selectfont
\begin{minipage}{115em}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \textbf{EINE ÜBERSCHRIFT}\\[0ex]
        {\fontsize{5}{9}\selectfont{}Eine Unter-Überschrift}
    \end{tabular}\\[3ex]
    \tikz\node[align=left] {%
    Karl Meier\\[3ex]Gustav Henrich\\[3ex]Lisa Schöne\\[3ex]Anton Dachs lang lang lang lang\\[3ex]Fritz Blumenthal};
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]